# Do I need to remove watchers on component destroyed() if I used the vm.$watch API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

As many of you know, Vue supports adding watchers using the declarative Single File Component API using the `watch` property, like so:

```js
watch: {
  // whenever question changes, this function will run
  question: function (newQuestion, oldQuestion) {
    this.answer = 'Waiting for you to stop typing...'
    this.debouncedGetAnswer()
  }
},
```

I'm relatively sure that following this approach, Vue takes care of the cleanup on component `destroyed()`. However, due to several reasons, I'm in need to add watchers dynamically using the `vm.$watch` API, like so:

```js
// keypath
vm.$watch('a.b.c', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  // do something
})
```

I know that the `vm.$watch` function returns an `unwatch()` function I can call, but I'm curious if this is strongly necessary to avoid things like memory leaks. I would think that on component destroyed, these watchers should stop existing as well since I think these watchers exist on component instance, but I'm not really sure. Also, nothing in the Vue.js docs or style guide mention that not calling `unwatch()` could lead to issues, which makes me think that I really shouldn't worry about not calling `unwatch()` on component `destroyed()`.

Does someone have a more conclusive answer to this question?

Comment: Don't think it's a proper answer, but i think Vue, will remove watchers automatically (asked guys in RU Vue chat)

Comment: Interesting... That's close to what I'm looking for and would be willing to award the correct answer flag, but do you think you could ask those guys from the RU Vue Chat if they have any kind of evidence for that? It could even be just a statement from a Vue.js core contributor. If you do, please add it as an answer 

Comment: Actually it was an answer of VueJs contributor. Also i don't want to pass it as answer, because it's not my answer)

Comment: Fair enough! Upvoted at the very least to try to award some kind of rep. Would have gladly awarded correct answer points though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the following response from the VueLand Discord from user `Cathrine` with the MVP role.

> it should be attached to the vm you're calling it on. So when the vm is destroyed, so is the watcher. {...} As you programmatically create the watcher, it makes sense to have a way to programmatically stop it. Afaik, that's the only purpose of it.

This, combined with @Asimple 's response seem to point that maybe I shouldn't worry about this too much. Thanks for your time everyone